# How to install gcc on linux without internet access?

Tags: linux, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to download gcc on a linux machine with no internet access. I was able to download the gcc.tar.xz file and transfer to offline linux machine. How do I proceed with installation?
I am unable to get internet access due to security protocols. All other threads I see have a solution to tether phone or use internet access another way, but that is not doable in my situation.

Thanks in advance!

I downloaded gcc.tar.xz file and unzipped. Tried to run make but make is not on system either.

Comment: You should download binary package for your distro, not source tarball. Then install it with package manager. Probably you also need to download and install dependencies, e.g. binutils package.